# How to write a earlystopping function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

My loss is like this:

```py
loss = np.sum(np.square(A-B))
```

How to write help function that would carry out "earlystopping" like in Keras?

Purpose:

If the loss is rising or does not fluctuate much then we stop and the get `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into Keras sources and find out code for EarlyStopping. I made my own callback, based on it:

```
class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if current is None:
            warnings.warn("Early stopping requires %s available!" % self.monitor, RuntimeWarning)

        if current < self.value:
            if self.verbose > 0:
                print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

And usage:

```
callbacks = [
    EarlyStoppingByLossVal(monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=1),
    # EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=0),
    ModelCheckpoint(
        kfold_weights_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, 
        verbose=0
    )
]
model.fit(
    X_train.astype('float32'), Y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    shuffle=True, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid),
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so that the question is marked as helpful for future visitors - nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Please add the necessary imports as well